# How do I install and use T-modLoader?

Tags: terraria, mods

I've always wanted to install mods to my Terraria game, but I have no idea how to use or install T-ModLoader. How do I install and use T-ModLoader?

Comment: If you scroll down on their website how to install it is the second thing listed. Did you even try to look this up?

Comment: no i asked this question for other people who don't know how to and are coming on this website to find the answer. @Robbie

Comment: While there's an argument to be made for trying to help others, we prefer if askers expend a modicum of effort on their own behalf before asking.  If the mod website does a good job of explaining this, we're not benefiting anyone by repeating it here.

Answer (score 0):

1. Download the game. They support Steam and GoG so you need to download it from one of those.
2. Download the TMODLOADER files. You can find all of the files [here](https://github.com/tModLoader/tModLoader/releases/tag/v0.11.5)
3. Find your Terraria folder. This is where the files will go
   4, Go into the properties of the downloaded zip file, scroll to the bottom, and unblock it. If it does not have an option to unblock it you can close the window.
4. Extract the zip file. You can download something to do this but most computers can do this by themselves.
5. Copy the extracted files to the Terraria file. Make sure to let them overwrite files when asked.

Actually creating the mods is much more complicated so I will not be adding that into this post. You can find a tutorial on how to create and use the mods [here](https://github.com/tModLoader/tModLoader/wiki/Basic-tModLoader-Modding-Guide)

Comment: They support GoG.

Comment: @brododragon On their website they only say Steam. Don't know why they wouldn't say you can use GoG as well. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: On the tmod TCF post it says Steam/GoG. It's writers that it's not on the webpage